# FAILED status in Elastix Reports

Tags: asterisk, failed, report, elastix

Please i want to know what is failed status means in the CDR report in Elastix, i to know if failed status mean that the call is dropped because the agent wasn't registered or the voice mail is full that's why we got failed status, Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+CDR+Specification):

> FAILED: The channel attempted to dial but the call failed.

So: the CDR doesn't contain the level of detail you need. For more details, you'll need to examine your sip log or the log for the transport you're using.